# Преобразование типов

Tags: c#, list

Ещё один простой вопрос по List. Есть `List<Class1>` и `List<Class2>`. `Class1` хранит всю информацию об объекте, `Class2` - инфу для вывода (несколько полей из `Class1`). Нужно по некоторой выборке получить список элементов `Class2`. Чувствую, что как-то можно, но познаний  не хватает понять как осуществить преобразование. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например так:

```
var result = list1.Select(item => new Class2(item.Field1, item.Field2)).ToList();
```

UP:

Не уверен, что правильно понял доп вопрос, но мб ответ здесь:

```
var result = list1.Select(item => new Class2{Prop1 = item.Prop1}).ToList();
```

UP2:

```
internal class A
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Value1 { get; set; }
}

internal class B
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}

internal class C
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }

    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

Собственно линк:

```
        var list3 = (from item in list1
                     let itemFromList2 = list2.First(ii => ii.ID == item.ID)
                     select new C
                         {
                             Value1 = item.Value1,
                             Value2 = iitemFromList2.Value2
                         }).ToList();
```

Ваша структура данных мне кажется не самой лучшей и связь по айди добавляет при поиске доп цикл и проверку. По производительности зависит от задачи и условия где вам это нужно. Линк в результате сводится к обычным циклам и данную реализацию явно можно улучшить.

Comment: ах да-да! Видел где-то уже такую конструкцию!! Спасибо!!

Comment: @wind, не хочется создавать ещё один простецкий вопрос) Не могли бы Вы ещё тогда подсказать? В списке Class1 у элементов свойство prop1 заполнено, как его заполнить в списке Class2, на основании общего ключа id? И вообще правильно ли мне для таких целей использовать списки? Возможно это слишком бьёт по производительности?

Comment: Не очень понял насчет ключа общего, можно пример?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то вы на основании одного списка с элементами создаете новый список и заполняете его данными из первого списка. У них должен быть общий ключ, ок - просто берете и просто заполняйте его.

Comment: да, ключ, т.е. одинаковое поле в том и в том списке. так как его заполнять? и по поводу производительности что скажете?

Comment: там на самом деле у меня 3 листа. и два из них заполнены. третий мы создавали в примере вот здесью теперь есть одно свойство, которое заполнено во втором листе, а нужно бы его получить и элементам первого. как-то так))

Comment: Зачем так, если можно, используя автомаппер, написать типа:
List<A> aList = mapper.Map<A, B>(bList);

Comment: Здесь немного сложней и надо не просто преобразовать из одного типа в другой, а собрать новый тип на основании двух других, да еще и чтобы они были связаны по некоему айди. Тоесть ваш упрощенный пример не подойдет.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте какой нибудь маппер, например (лично я использую) EmitMapper. Маппер копирует объект одного типа в объект другого типа по совпадающим полям. Также поддерживает маппинг списков объектов разных типов.

Comment: Кстате отличный вариант! правда я обычно пользуюсь AutoMapper, но ето не суть...